# What is the best way to extract the highest dimension geometry from a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION?

Tags: postgis

I am looking for the best approach to convert a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION to MULTI* geometry type using the highest dimension geometry in the collection.

So basically a [ST_CollectionExtract](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_CollectionExtract.html) where the second parameter is automatically chosen.

I am using PostGIS 2.3 and I also have these functions loaded: https://github.com/pedrogit/postgisaddons

Comment: What would be the result if geometrycollection contains for example two multipolygons and one point? The first one of the multipolygons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ST_Dimension`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dimension.html), which returns the largest dimension of a GeometryCollection's components.

For an undoubtedly excellent reason that's well-rooted in thoughtfully-drafted specifications, [`ST_Dimension`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dimension.html) produces dimensions starting at `0`, while [`ST_CollectionExtract`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html) accepts dimensions beginning with `1`. (In other words, [`ST_Dimension`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dimension.html) uses `2` to indicate a polygon, while [`ST_CollectionExtract`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html) uses `3` to indicate a polygon.) So to extract the highest-dimension geometries from a GeometryCollection, you would use:

```
SELECT ST_CollectionExtract(geom, 1 + ST_Dimension(geom))
FROM my_data;
```

Comment: Ok, well you learn something every day :-) That is a tad simpler than my convoluted CASE. Perhaps I'll leave my answer anyway as an example of how not to do it.

Comment: well, I implemented a "workaround" about an hour before this posted: ST_DimensionMax (ST_Dump, then a max on ST_Dimension). Guess I'll be renaming that one to ST_Useless!

Answer (score 1):

I think there must be a more elegant way of doing this, but one approach would be to combine three UNION SELECTS with three CASE statements testing for each geomety type, combined with an ST_IsEmpty test returning -1 if the type is not found, and then use the max of the result of that in a final select. This returns a MultiPolygon, as I used the union of the test input geometries in the subquery extracts. This would need tweaking to deal with @user30148's question

```
WITH geoms (geom) AS 
     (VALUES 
          (ST_Makepoint(0,0)), 
          (ST_Buffer(ST_Makepoint(1, 10), 2)), 
          (ST_Buffer(ST_Makepoint(50, 50), 5))), 
    collection(geom) AS (
       SELECT ST_Union(geom) 
         FROM geoms
   ),
   extracts(geom_type) AS (
      SELECT CASE 
               WHEN NOT ST_Isempty(ST_CollectionExtract(geom, 3)) 
               THEN 3 
               ELSE -1 END 
       FROM collection 
        UNION 
      SELECT CASE 
               WHEN NOT ST_Isempty(ST_CollectionExtract(geom, 2)) 
               THEN 2 
               ELSE -1 
               END 
        FROM collection 
        UNION
      SELECT CASE 
               WHEN NOT ST_Isempty(ST_CollectionExtract(geom, 1)) 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE -1 END 
         FROM collection
  ), 
  max_type(geom_type) AS (
       SELECT max(geom_type) FROM extracts
  )
  SELECT ST_CollectionExtract(geom, geom_type)
    FROM collection, max_type;
```